# How to remove a row in r based on the row name

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have a dataframe and the rownames are words rather than numbers, how can I delete a specific row based on its name?

For example if a row name is "Bacteria", how can I delete only that row named "Bacteria"?

Comment: Just do `df1[row.names(df1) != "Bacteria",]`

Comment: `%in%` maybe better than `!=` - `df1[!row.names(df1) %in% c("Bacteria", "Virus"),]`

Comment: @akrun make this an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can create a logical vector by making use of the comparison operator with `row.names` and use that row index to subset the rows.  If `df1` is the data.frame object name, then do

```
df1[row.names(df1) != "Bacteria", , drop = FALSE]
```